# How does the block reward work?

Tags: block-reward

There is an equation for the block reward. Say that changes. Would that invalidate every other old block? Because as I understand it the genesis block for instance used a different formula.

Comment: Please see also this Q&A: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/monero-block-reward-schedule

Comment: "Say that changes. Would that invalidate every other old block?" <- No. The reward function (whatever it currently is), is applied at time of block being mined; previous blocks are unaffected.